# nativescript carousel by javascript

Tags: carousel, nativescript

I want to create a horizontal scroll-view with stack-layout similar to 'olx' app. But the problem i am facing is to achieve endless scroll or carousel like scroll.

in the below link, carousel template was already implemented but it was too complicated to understand.
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=sRSad7&v=6

how to build and achieve endless horizontal scroll of the icons in stack-layout like in 'OLX' app. I am not expecting someone to code but just a flowchart of doing things would be very helpful.

Comment: You have to try [nativescript-pager](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-pager) plugin for this purpose. ScrollView uses real views, Pager will reuse the views to improve performance just like a ListView. If you want endless scroll, then you must be having endless number of items Or shift your items in array as you go.

Comment: @Manoj  thank you for the answer, i'm not working on endless items,so can you little elaborate on how to put the items in array and shift. i.e first i will create a stacklayout horizontal. then put some 10 items inside it, now i will scroll it to right then it will stop at the end. i have an 'id' for that stack layout can you tell me in little detail how to shift this in array please....